# Specifying ThisType for a delegate function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I provide a function called createAction which takes a delegate as a parameter.  Within that delegate function I want to specify the "this" type.  Here is the code:

```typescript
    function createAction(delegate: (...args: any) => any): void {
        ...
    }
```

Here is an example of the designed usage of it:

```typescript
    createAction(() => {
        console.log(this.state.name);
    });
```

The issue I have is that `this.state` is obviously undefined, because `state` is not a known property of `this`.  How do I change the definition of the createAction function to specify the type of `this` within the delegate please?

I've tried this and it does not work:

```typescript
    function createAction(delegate: ((...args: any[]) => any) & ThisType<{ state: StateType }>): void {
        ...
    }
```

and this:

```typescript
    function createAction(delegate: (this: { state: StateType }, ...args: any[]) => any): void {
        ...
    }
```

Is this even possible and does anyone have any other ideas please?

Comment: The second solution should've worked, based on how I understood your question. What is the problem with it?

Comment: The second solution does work if I use it like this: `createAction(function () { console.log(this.state.name); });` but not like this: `createAction(() => { console.log(this.state.name); });`.